# what is the install RAR to create Resource Adapter in websphere

Tags: websphere-7

I am trying to create Resource Adapter in websphere. It is assking RAR path. I do not have installed RAR in my system. Could you please help how to install RAR

Comment: JCA compliant resource adapters usually comes in the RAR archive. That's why you have to install RAR. Please provide more information in your question, what kind of adapter you are trying to install, is it JCA compliant, etc. More details about installing adapters are in [infocenter](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tdat_crtresadp.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-23-2-1&lang=en)

Comment: yes. it is JCA compliant  resource. I want to establish connection with mainframe.